# how to add a scroll bar in data grid column

Tags: wpfdatagrid

Example dgTest datagrid row height=40 , one of the datagrid column contain text field .it doesn't shows full details . I would like to set scroll bar on that column . when row size is greater than 40 then the scroll bar should show , it will help me to a clear view  ....

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a `ScrollViewer`

Something like this

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <DataGrid>
 //ur code 
 </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

check this out [Data grid height is too tall when using word-wrap in text block column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857530/data-grid-height-is-too-tall-when-using-word-wrap-in-text-block-column)